# Aggregations on Lead & LAG in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

This is with respect to oracle
Input

```
CUSTID          FROMDT         ACTIVITY     NEXTDATE
100000914   31/01/2015 14:23:51 Bet         3.999996
100000914   31/01/2015 14:29:07 Bet         3.999996
100000914   31/01/2015 14:32:59 Bet         2
100000914   31/01/2015 14:35:35 Bet         1.999998
100000914   31/01/2015 16:52:32 Settlement  3.999996
100000914   31/01/2015 16:54:39 Settlement  1.999998
100000914   31/01/2015 16:55:04 Settlement  2
100000914   31/01/2015 16:57:00 Settlement  3.999996
100000914   31/01/2015 16:57:10 Bet         3
100000914   31/01/2015 19:21:15 Settlement  3
```

Result

```
CUSTID      ACTIVITY    AMOUNT      
100000914   Bet         11.99999    
100000914   Settlement  11.99999    
100000914   Bet          3          
100000914   Settlement   3
```

Result should have sum of amount for every activity change

Thanks

Comment: This is not a question, this is a code-request. SO is not a code writing service. Show your effort.

Comment: Not programming specific !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CUSTID,
       ACTIVITY,
       total - LAG( total, 1, 0 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY FROMDT ) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT CUSTID,
         FROMDT,
         ACTIVITY,
         SUM( NEXTDATE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY FROMDT ) AS total,
         CASE ACTIVITY
              WHEN LEAD( ACTIVITY ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY FROMDT )
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
              END AS has_changed
  FROM   your_table
)
WHERE  has_changed = 1;
```

**Outputs**:

```
CUSTID    ACTIVITY   TOTAL
--------- ---------- --------
100000914 Bet        11.99999
100000914 Settlement 11.99999
100000914 Bet               3
100000914 Settlement        3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify groups of consecutive values.  The rest is then aggregation.

One method is the difference of row numbers approach:

```
select custid, activity, sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by custid order by fromdt) -
              row_number() over (partition by custid, activity order by fromdt)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by custid, grp, activity
order by custid, max(fromdt);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon
Result
CUSTID  ACTIVITY AMOUNT  Order
100000914 Bet  11.99999 1
100000914 Settlement 11.99999 2
100000914 Bet  3  3
100000914 Settlement 3  4


CUSTID  ACTIVITY AMOUNT
100000914 Bet  11.99999
100000914 Bet  3
100000914 Settlement 3
100000914 Settlement 11.99999

Answer should be this way based upon the activity change

Comment: `ORDER BY CUSTID, MAX( FROMDT )`

Comment: select custid, activity, sum(amount)
from (select jg_dig_test.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by custid order by fromdate) - row_number() over (partition by custid, activity order by fromdate)
             ) as grp
      from jg_dig_test
     ) jg_dig_test
group by custid, grp, activity
ORDER BY CUSTID, MAX( FROMDaTe )
;

Comment: @nkalis . . . If the difference is the ordering in the output, then you just need the appropriate `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select custid, activity, sum(amount)
from (select jg_dig_test.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by custid order by fromdate) - row_number() over (partition by custid, activity order by fromdate)
             ) as grp
      from jg_dig_test
     ) jg_dig_test
group by custid, grp, activity
ORDER BY CUSTID, MAX( FROMDaTe )
;
```